# Eloquent relationship with 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Laravel.

I try to develop a variable profilesystem in Laravel and I got 3 tables ('User', 'User_Fields', 'Fields').

The structure of the `Fields` table is following:
[image: Fields]

The structure of the `user_fields` table is following:
[image: user_fields]

The `User` table is the standard table which came with Laravel 5

Now I want to get all fields from `user_fields` depending on which `user` is selected or logged in. If the `user_field` doesn't exists, the model should return `null` or create a new record for the `user_field`.

I tried a lot of "solutions" which came with eloquent like (`hasManyThrough`, `belongsToMany`) but I don't get the result I wanted.

Is there any solution with relationship methods?

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my bad english :/

Comment: welcome to SO , what did you tried?

Comment: i have the fields table (in this table are all profile fields declared) and the user_fields table (this table contains the value and is realted to the user_id and the field_id ) now i try to retrive all profile fields from the fields table with the value from user_fields table but it should return **null** if the related user_field doesnt exists. Do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `belongsToMany()->withPivot()` to [retrieve the intermediate table columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).  Your `user_fields` is your pivot table so on your user model you should have:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Field::class, 'user_fields')->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

Then you can access your values for a user by:

```
$user = User::find($id);
foreach($user->fields as $field) {
    $field->pivot->value;
}
```

Comment: for example i have the fields: firstname,lastname,address,postalcode,city and country in my fields_table, but in my user_fields table only exists firstname->john and lastname->doe. at this point ur solution works fine but i want to retrive the rest of the fields_table like address, postalcode etc. wich has no value from user_fields .. thanks alot for ur help :)